# YII - Attaching behavior to validator

Tags: validation, yii, yii-behaviour

I want to attach a behavior to a validator defined in the rules() function of a form. I can not figure out how. If I do something like this

```
array('page',  'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true, 'min' => 1, 'message' => '{attribute} is invalid'
    , 'behaviors' => array( 
        'error' => array( 'class' => 'CErrorBehavior'),
        ),
    ),
```

I get the following exception

```
Property "CNumberValidator.behaviors" is not defined.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The `CValidator` class doesn't expose behaviors like that. You could overload [`CModel::createValidators`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#createValidators-detail) and set behaviors explicitly in there.

Comment: What are you want to do?

Comment: I want to add an error property without extending the CValidator class as it would mean that I have to "rewrite" standard validators